# Return array of matches in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get Excel to return an array of 1s and 0s for a column depending on whether it finds a match in another look-up column. For example, my column might be

A

B

C

C

A

B

and my look-up column might be

A

B

and I'm looking for Excel to return the array {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1} to use this in a SUMPRODUCT involving several of these look-up arrays. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B2,0))`.

Comment: Or just `=COUNTIF(B1:B2,A1:A6)`

Answer (score 0):

### Evaluating Formulas <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
Formula                             Evaluation

=MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B2,0)               ={1;2;#N/A;#N/A;1;2}
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B2,0))     ={TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE}
=--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B2,0))   ={1;1;0;0;1;1} 

The Opposite
 
=--ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A6,B1:B2,0))   ={0;0;1;1;0;0}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ***Microsoft-365*** can try-

```
=XLOOKUP(A1:A6,B1:B2,--(B1:B2<>""),0)
```

[image]